# how to align in printf function

Tags: alignment, printf

I want to make the printf function print from right to left because this program convert the value of number to binary and I want it to be printed in proper form for example if I convert 16 it is written like that 00001 but it must look like that 10000 so does anyone know how to do that thanks in advance

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   int x,rem;

   printf("please enter number: ");
   scanf("%d",&x);

   while (x !=0)
   {
       rem=x%2;
       if (rem==0)
       {
           printf("0");
       }
       else
       {
          printf("1");
       }
       x = x/2;
       rem = 0;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is:

```
void print_binary(int x)
{
    int skip = 1;
    unsigned int mask = 1 << 31;
    while(mask > 0){
        if(x & mask){
            skip = 0;
            printf("1");
        }else{
            if(!skip) printf("0");
        }
        mask >>= 1;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

This will print the binary number without trailing zeroes.

If you rather want the result to be stored in a string, you can use:

```
#include <string.h>
void int_to_binary(int x, char * buff) // buff size must be >= 32 !
{
    buff[0] = '\0'; // ensure string ends with \0
    unsigned int mask = 1 << 31;
    for (; mask > 0; mask >>= 1)
    {
        strcat(buff, (x & mask) ? "1" : "0");
    }
}
```

To check both codes, use:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int x;
    printf("please enter number: ");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    char bin[32];
    int_to_binary(x, bin);
    printf("%s\n", bin);
    print_binary(x);
}
```

What we do is using a mask, which in binary is one "1" beginning on the far left and moving one step right at each loop. The "&" is a bite-wise operator (I let you google it to know how it works). If you need more explanation, feel free to ask.

Comment: thanks for the help I know the bit masking and bitwise operations I use it in embedded C to access pins :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<stdlib.h> 
int main() 
{ 
      int binary[20]; 
      int q,i=0;
      printf("Enter the decimal no\n"); 
      scanf("%d",&q); 
      while(q > 0) 
      { 
           binary[i]=q%2; 
           i++; 
           q=q/2;
      }

      for(int j=i-1;j>=0;j--) 
      {
            printf("%d",binary[j]);
      }

return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Please, indent your code properly when posting on stack overflow.

Comment: @Shitsu: Sorry for the wrong post i just complied and edited my code.